# React Native -- Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property. (Device)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I created react native app and add Native navigation to switch between screens. After that an issue started to comes up when I run it on the Device.

Error --

```
assets/routes/homeStack.js (680:882)
Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
(Device)
  Evaluating module://react-navigation.js
  Evaluating module://react-navigation-stack.js
  Evaluating module://assets/routes/homeStack.js.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

But when I run it on web , it runs perfectly and navigation process also fine.
Here is the navigation stack file.

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import Buttons from '../../components/Buttons'
import Waiting from '../../components/Waiting'


const screens ={
  Home:{
    screen:Buttons
  },
  Wait:{
    screen:Waiting
  }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

How can I fix this ?
complete code and online emulator is here - https://snack.expo.dev/@codewithbanchi/pincode

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json this is the code.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-constants": "~11.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "4.1.1",
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons/Feather": "*",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons/Feather/Delete": "*"
  }
}
```

To solve try removing this line along with the comma in the previous line.

```js
"react-native-vector-icons/Feather/Delete": "*"
```

Your code should look like this.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-constants": "~11.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "4.1.1",
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons/Feather": "*",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome": "*"
  }
}
```